# Force Renovate to update libraries before updating service

Tags: renovate

we have a couple of spring boot microservices. Those services depend on our libraries. Those libraries depend on spring boot dependencies (as do the services).

We are using Renovate to keep those dependencies up to date. Having this chain of dependencies means that the libraries have to be updated first before the services are allowed to be updated, otherwise the same spring boot dependency with different versions are included which leads to very strange behavior and unrelated error messages.

Most of the time this happens with updates to `spring-boot-starter-parent`, because this defines most of the dependency's versions.

Is there a way to have Renovate update the service's dependency to `spring-boot-starter-parent` together with the dependency a library, when the library uses the same version of `spring-boot-starter-parent`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`packageRules`](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#packagerules) like this to group updates. You have probably to update the match function.

```json
{
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackagePatterns": ["^org.springframework.boot:"],
      "groupName": "Sprint boot packages"
    }
  ]
}
```